# passing a parameter with a state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two pages, on is responsible of listing some records and the other is for showing more information when we click on a record.

This is how I list the records :

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li ng-repeat="offre in offres | orderBy:'-dateCreation' | filter:{etat:'true'} | limitTo:limit">
     <h4><a href="" ng-click="goTo(offre.titre,offre.codeOffre)">{{offre.titre}}</a></h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on some record it will invoke the method goTo() which is as following :

```
$scope.goTo=function(titreOffre,codeOffre){
    titreOffre=titreOffre.replace(/ /g,"-");
    $state.go('app.job',{titreOffre:titreOffre,codeOffre: codeOffre});
};
```

And this is the `app.job` state :

```
.state('app.job', {
  url : '/job/:titreOffre',
  params : {
    'codeOffre' : null
  },
  templateUrl : 'views/tmpl/job-details.html'
})
```

in the `job-details.html` page I use the codeOffre which I passed to the `app.job` as a parameter to get the data about this record as following :

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/offre/offres/' + codeOffre)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function (error) {
      return 'There was an error getting data';
    });
```

So this all works fine, the only problem is when I display the `job-details.html` page and then I refresh it the `codeOffre` which I passed a param is no longer keeps the value I passed to it and it set to null.

how can I solve this ?

Comment: Since the param is not listed in the url, you cannot access it on reloading unless it is stored somewhere like `sessionStorage` as mentioned in the answers. Other option is to add it to the url. But I suppose you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Chinni Yeah that was I thought myself, I'm going to use the `job/:codeOffre/:titreOffre`, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

**1. Pass it in the url:**

```
url: '/job/:titreOffre/:codeOffer'
```

**2. Use sessionStorage:**

Define getter and setter methods in a service to read, write and update the value of `codeOffer`. And use these methods in the controller appropriately.

Comment: Thanks that's was I thought at first glance but I wanted to see if there was some other way to do it, but it seems there is not.